Redis closing connection after request
So i'm using java with spring data redis 2.4.8 for caching, when i'm trying to get values from cache (i have a list of keys), in logs i see that redis always closing connection:
2024-04-02 09:16:14.851 DEBUG 1655457 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.d.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils    : Fetching Redis Connection from RedisConnectionFactory
2024-04-02 09:16:14.943 DEBUG 1655457 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.d.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils    : Closing Redis Connection.
2024-04-02 09:16:14.944 DEBUG 1655457 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.d.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils    : Fetching Redis Connection from RedisConnectionFactory
2024-04-02 09:16:15.035 DEBUG 1655457 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.d.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils    : Closing Redis Connection.
2024-04-02 09:16:15.036 DEBUG 1655457 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.d.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils    : Fetching Redis Connection from RedisConnectionFactory
2024-04-02 09:16:15.127 DEBUG 1655457 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.d.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils    : Closing Redis Connection.

How to make connection keep alive ? Here is my config:
    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(redisHost);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(redisPort);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(redisPassword);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(redisDbName);

        LettuceClientConfiguration.LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder builder = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder();
        builder.clientOptions(ClientOptions.builder().autoReconnect(true)
                .socketOptions(SocketOptions.builder().keepAlive(true).build())
                .build()).useSsl();

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, builder.build());
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper));
        return redisTemplate;
    }

I found the KeepAlive setting in the socket options, but it didn't help.
               .socketOptions(SocketOptions.builder().keepAlive(true).build())

You need to add a connection pool, give you some example code:
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

    // other configurations...

    GenericObjectPoolConfig<Connection> poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig<>();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(100); // the maximum number of objects that can be allocated by the pool
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(50); // the maximum number of "idle" instances that can be held in the pool
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(10); // the minimum number of objects allowed in the pool before the pool tries to create more

    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)) // Set the command timeout
            .shutdownTimeout(Duration.ZERO) // Set the shutdown timeout 
            .clientOptions(socketOptions) 
            .useSsl() // use SSL
            .poolConfig(poolConfig) // add the pool config here
            .build();

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, clientConfig);
}


Thanks for answer, but i dont have such method .poolConfig
Also i dont have dependency for GenericObjectPoolConfig

I think it's from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig;
import io.lettuce.core.Connection;

i don't have method .poolConfig, i think you're using another version of spring-data-redis, i'm using 2.4.8
